# uncaught reference id not defined

Tags: javascript, forms, uncaught-reference-error

I am trying to create a button to clear out these 2 forms as seen in the following code. I was able to figure out that the code for clearing the form only works for the form coded last. So if I put the code for form id zxy first, and try to clear the form I get an error but the code for clearing form id manualEntry works. But if I paste the code for form id zxy below form id manualEntry, the opposite is true.

Whichever form is on top gets the error message "Uncaught Reference Error: x not defined.

Hope this is clear.
Here is my code.

```html
<img id="barcodereader" src="img/scanner.JPG" width=25px class="refButtons"> Click to toggle between using a barcode reader or manual entry<br>
<div id="withreader">
  <div class="reagentlog">
    Some text<br>
    <form id="zxy">
      <label>Scan barcode here:</label>
      <input type='text' name='barcodescan' id='barcodescan'><br>
      <label>Product GTIN</label>
      <input type='text' id='gtin' name='gtin'><br>
      <label>Number of Units:</label>
      <input type='text' name='nmbrunits'><br>
      <label>Open Date:</label>
      <input type='date' id='opendate' name='opendate' onChange="gtinLookup()"><br>
      <label id='expdays'>Expiration Days: </label><br>
      <label>Open Exiration Date:</label>
      <input type='date' name='opnexpdate' id='opexpdate'><br>

      <input type="button" onClick="clearForm2()" value="Clear form">
      <button type="submit" name="reagent-log">Submit</button>

      <br>
      <span>    
        Some text.<br>
        Some more text<br>
        A<br>
        B<br>
        C<br>
        D<br>
      </span>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="withoutreader">
  Complete the form below.<br>
  <div class='reagentlog'>
    <form id="manualEntry" action='aaaa.php' method='POST'>

      <!-- <p title='By default this list will show products with available inventory. To see an extended list of product select the check box.'>
                                <input type='checkbox' name='default' >
                                Show entire reagent list.
                                </p> -->

      <label>Select Reagent</label>
      <select Reagent='New' id='reagentList' name='reagent' onChange="clearInputs()">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <?php
           reagentList ($conn);
        ?>
      </select><br>

      <!--   <div id='optionList'> -->

      <label>Choose option</label>
      <select name='rgt-option'>
        <option value="routine">Routine Use</option>
        <option value="expired">Expired Reagent</option>
        <option value="lend">Lending</option>
        <option value="adjust">Adjusting Inventory</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select><br>
      <label>Number of Units:</label>
      <input type='text' id='nmbrunits2' name='nmbrunits'><br>
      <label>Open Date:</label>
      <input type='date' id='opendate2' name='opendate' onChange='getExpDate()'><br>
      <label>Expiration Days:</label>
      <span id='expdays2'></span><br>
      <label>Open Exiration Date:</label>
      <!--    <p id='opexpdate2b'></p> -->
      <input type='date' id='opexpdate2' name='expdate'><br>
      <input type="button" onClick="clearForm()" value="Clear form">
      <button type="submit" name="reagent-log">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script> 
function clearForm() {
    manualEntry.reset();
    document.getElementById('opexpdate2').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('expdays2').innerHTML = "";
}




function clearForm2() {
    zxy.reset();
    document.getElementById('opendate').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('opexpdate').innerHTML = "";    
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is "Uncaught Reference Error: x not defined." the actual error or does X change when you swap the forms?

Comment: yes, X represents the form id

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue while troubleshooting another problem.
There was an unclosed form tag in a different file. That file was getting called in the file with the above code. The opening form tag was written in the HTML code before an opening PHP tag, and the closing form tag was written within the PHP code. Apparently, it didn't like this. I moved the closing form tag out of the PHP code and placed it outside of the closing PHP tag and everything worked.